# Pytest : how to create and read a file inside a test

Tags: testing, pytest

I have the environment to test.
So my test calls a function that generates a file inside the `output_file` and I need to check the file during the test time.

But I don't know why my file is saved inside the `output_file` AFTER pytest has finished its work, and my test always fails.

I have two test functions:
The first one is to call the function to generate the file that I need to check.
and de second function is to read it.

Occurs that, if I run just the first test function - everything is ok... the file is kept inside the output_file directory
But if I run all the scrip (with the two test_functions) the second function does not find the file of the first test and just when all the scrip finishes my file is saved.

There is a reason for that?
I can not change the function to save the file in another place.
How can pytest allow my function to save the file inside the output_file during the time of the execution of the test, in a way that I can read it?
There is a fixture to that?

|-teste
|--output_file
|--mytest

```
test_function_one()
   pid = os.getpid()
   call_function_to_test('cliente',pid)
   assert 
test_function_second()
   with open('output_file/'mydoc.csv')as ...
```

raises FileNotFoundError

Comment: Why save the file at all when you could just return it from a fixture?

Comment: I need to check the content of the file. How can I return it from a fixture?

Comment: Hi, tests should be isolated from one another (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/2204462/11246056), which does not seem to be the case here. Your first test should assert the existence of the file the first function is supposed to create when called, whereas your second test should assert that the second function reads an already created file the way it supposed to.

Answer (score 5):

If I understand well : you have two functions to test (two [UUT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_under_test)).
If this is the case and you have two functions to test, so in unit testing you should write two different tests, since each test should be isolated.

For that, you should recreate the file for the second test.

**BUT**: since you "cannot" use the first function to create your file (otherwise you depends on a function of your program for a test, so if you change this function you break the test)
I strongly suggest to use [pytest fixtures](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html) here.

Especially the built-in [tmp_path fixture](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/reference.html#tmp-path) which will provide you a temporary directory for free and will take care of empty it at the end of the test suite run.

So in your case, I would suggest to keep the first test (that creates the file) as it is now (since it pass).
This test is only for testing that your function create a file.

For the second test, you just want to test if the function is able to read a file as expected. So use pytest fixtures for that, which will create the file for you :

```py
import os
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def output_file(tmp_path):
    # create your file manually here using the tmp_path fixture
    # or just import a static pre-built mock file
    # something like : 
    target_output = os.path.join(tmp_path,'mydoc.csv')
    with open(target_output, 'w+'):
        # write stuff here
    return target_output


def test_function_second(output_file):
   with open(output_file) as ...
```

In addition :
Each fixture should be saved (or imported) in `conftest.py` if you need to share them across different unit tests (read the doc [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html#conftest-py-sharing-fixtures-across-multiple-files))

Comment: Thank you so much @jossefaz. You helped me a lot.